# How can I delete unapplied migrations?

Tags: python, django, migrate

I would like to delete only unapplied migrations, `showmigrations`  gives:

```
[X] 0011_auto_20190917_1522
[X] 0012_auto_20190917_1600
[ ] 0013_auto_20190917_1638
[ ] 0014_auto_20190917_1647
[ ] 0015_auto_20190917_1652
[ ] 0016_auto_20190917_1654
[ ] 0017_auto_20190917_1704
```

`...`

I have 21 unapplied migrations! The question is when migrations are unapplied, don't have any effect on database, right? Can I just delete them from "myapp" migrations folder and after that to do `makemigrations` and `migrate` again?

Comment: You should be careful with this since it is not said that because your development database is migrated to `0012`, that other databases (for example in production) are not updated further in the migration chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: You *can* do that, but you should be careful, and take some situations into account.

---

You *can* remove the migrations that are not yet applied to the database. But you should be very careful with that, since it is not said that if the migrations are not applied to one database (for example a database you use for development), that other databases (for example in production) are not migrated already further in the migration chain.

You thus should only remove migrations for which you are sure that no database has already made the migrations. If you delete migrations that have been applied already. The database(s) might for example have already constructed tables, columns, etc. If you later run the new migration, that migration will contain modifications starting from the point where you removed the migrations, and thus might run into errors, since that migration will aim to construct a table that already exists.

Another potential problem is that migrations might contain [**`RunPython`** operations [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython). These are usually small pieces of code that one has inserted *manually*. For example to replace all the records such that a specific column now has a certain value. By removing these migrations, and by making new migrations, these `RunPython` operations will be lost. The name of the migrations (it contains `auto`) suggests that the migrations have been constructed automatically, but it is not impossible that a programmer later modified such file, and thus inserted a `RunPython` operation.

Having multiple migrations is not a severe problem. Django will run a *topological sorting* algorithm on the "migration graph", and this can be done in *O(n)*. Having a large amount of files is usually not a severe bottleneck.

You might want to consider using [**`squashmigrations`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) to group migrations together in a new file. This will take into account the `RunPython` operations, and thus might be more safe than squashing migrations by removing and recreating migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just delete them from migrations folder (dont delete the migrations folder itself).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they are not applied to the database, you can simply remove them.